# Wordpress Fatal Error How To Fixed

Tags: wordpress

[Wordpress Fatal Error How To Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q342z.png)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 295561 bytes) in /home/techmysc/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1475

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not a wordpress expert, but I would search "Allowed memory size exhausted"  and try to locate what wb-db.php is doing on line 1475...  include this kind of research in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Step :1 Edit your wp-config.php file and enter something like:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

Step :2 If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini

```
memory_limit = 256M ;
```

A complete referance regarding (It works for Wordpress and woocomerce issue ) :

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/increasing-the-wordpress-memory-limit/

Answer (score 0):

I've tried by increasing the memory limit but nothing worked for me.
Then I upgraded the php version from 5.3 which was the default for my website to 5.6 from cPanel and then it worked very well.

1. Log in to your cpanel.
2. Under software panel click on "Select PHP version".
3. Then change your php from the current version to something newer version and check.